# How do I load up child views in a View sequentially on appear

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am trying to load my subviews inside my parent view GameView. Basically I would like each player subview inside GameView to upload sequentially. So what I did was have my animation transitions to increment on delays by 1.5. But still, all the views inside the game view are loaded, and then the screen is presented. How could I make this more sequential? Thanks

```
struct GameView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game:GameViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0.21, green: 0.40, blue: 0.30, opacity: 1.00)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                HandView.init(hand: game.dealer).offset(x: 0, y: 0).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(6))

                HStack {PlayerView.init(player: self.game.players[0]).padding(.all).rotationEffect(Angle.init(degrees: 90)).scaledToFit().scaleEffect(0.7).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0))
                    Spacer().frame(minWidth: 10)
                    PlayerView.init(player: self.game.players[2]).padding(.all).rotationEffect(Angle.init(degrees: -90)).scaledToFit().scaleEffect(0.7).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(2))
                }
                PlayerView.init(player: self.game.players[1]).padding(.all).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(4))
                HStack(spacing: 0)
                { Button(action: {
                    self.game.resetGame()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Reset")
                }).offset(x: -8, y: 0)}.padding(.leading, -100)

            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
struct PlayerView: View {
    @State var player:Player
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(0..<self.player.hands.count, id: \.self) {
                        index in ZStack {
                            Spacer()
                            HandView.init(hand: self.player.hands[index])
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer().frame(height: 45)
                    Text(self.player.id).bold().font(Font.system(size: 20))
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.all)
                if self.player.isBust{
                    self.bust
                }
            }
            if !player.isRobot{
                VStack{Button(action: {
                    self.player.requestCard()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Hit Me!")
                })
                    Button(action: {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { // 1 sec delay
                            self.player.requestCard()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Stay")
                    })}
                    .offset(x: 10, y: 0)}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience you can use this View extension to trigger an animation when a view *appears*:

```
extension View {
    func animate(using animation: Animation, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        return onAppear {
            withAnimation(animation) {
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple demo of sequentially showing two circles (with an initial delay):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var opacityCircle1 = 0.0
    @State var opacityCircle2 = 0.0

    @State var animationsLoaded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .opacity(opacityCircle1)
                .animate(using: Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).delay(1)) { self.opacityCircle1 = 1.0 }
            Button(action: {
                print("tapped")
            }) {
                Circle()
                    .opacity(opacityCircle2)
                    .animate(using: Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).delay(3)) { self.opacityCircle2 = 1.0 }
            }
            .disabled(!animationsLoaded)
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
              self.animationsLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `self.animationsLoaded` variable is introduced to control actions for buttons (if you want your buttons to respond only after the animations finish).

Comment: hmm so is opacity the best way to do it or are there any others? I have some tappable buttons inside this view so opacity might cause issues with that as I dont want the user to be able to click a button untill its loaded

Comment: @RohanGarg There may be other solutions obviously, but I believe opacity is exactly what you need in this case - the views will always be present and the layout will stay the same. I updated my answer with a possibility to perform actions only after everything is loaded (it's just a concept since you have custom views instead of buttons, but I hope you get the idea).

Comment: quick question how could I handle a dynamic number of circles?

Comment: @RohanGarg With arrays perhaps? One for circles, one for opacities (`@State var opacityArray: [Double]`) and use it in a loop.

Comment: how do I get my parent view to pass this newly computed array? My use case is that the parent gets the number of circles from its ViewModel environment object. But how would the parent then create an array of opacities for its child view? Does my viewmodel need to be giving these opacities then?

Comment: @RohanGarg Please post another question. It's better not to ask detailed questions in the comments. And this way more people will be able to help you.